# Compute the largest natural number $n$ such that $2^n$ divides $S=\binom{2}{1}+\binom{4}{2}+\binom{8}{4}+\cdots+\binom{2^{100}}{2^{99}}$

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

Honestly, I'm pretty stuck on this. I've made some basic observations, but I'm not sure they'll help.

- For any positive integer $k$, $$\binom{2^k}{2^{k-1}}=\frac{(2^k)!}{((2^{k-1})!)^2}$$ I was thinking that the factorial being squared in the denominator might allow for some nice symmetry, but I can't seem to see any. This binomial coefficient also counts the number of ways to choose $2^{k-1}$ objects from a set of $2^k$ objects, but I couldn't find a combinatorial representation for the sum as a whole.
- Using Legendre's formula, $v_2((2^k)!)=2^k-1$ and $v_2((2^{k-1})!)=2^{k-1}-1$. So, $v_2 \binom{2^k}{2^{k-1}}=(2^k-1)-2(2^{k-1}-1)=1$.

Comment: Try some numbers smaller than $100$ and see if you get a pattern.

Comment: @SarveshRavichandranIyer That's probably not enough. Instead, proving $$\binom{2^{k+1}}{2^k} \equiv -2\ ( \text{mod}\ 8 )$$ for all $k\geq 1$ could work.

Comment: @Cosmo You're right, good point.

Comment: @Cosmo if I get it correctly, $-2\cdot 100 \equiv 0 \pmod 8$ so we need an even higher power of 2?

Comment: @DS The first term (where $k = 0$) equals $2$, not $-2$.

Comment: Can't you just calculate the 2-adic valuation of $\binom{2^{k+1}}{2^k}$?

Comment: @Cosmo that makes sense.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know how to interpret the 2-adic result, but I'll write a solution soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $$\binom{2^k}{2^{k-1}}=\frac{(2^k)!}{(2^k-2^{k-1})!(2^{k-1})!}=\frac{(2^k)!}{(2^{k-1})!^2}$$

Using Legendre's formula, we know that $$v_2 ((2^k)!)=\sum^{\infty}_{i=1} \left \lfloor \frac{2^k}{2^i} \right \rfloor=2^{k}-1$$ and $$v_2((2^{k-1})!)=\sum^{\infty}_{i=1} \left \lfloor \frac{2^{k-1}}{2^i} \right \rfloor=2^{k-1}-1$$
So, we can say that $$v_2 \binom{2^k}{2^{k-1}}=(2^k-1)-2(2^{k-1}-1)=1$$

For $k \geq 1$, we see that $\binom{2^k}{2^{k-1}} \equiv 2 \pmod{4}$. Thus, $S \equiv 2(100) \pmod{4} \equiv 0 \pmod{4}$.

Similarly, we see that for $k \geq 2$, $\binom{2^k}{2^{k-1}} \equiv -2 \pmod{8}$ and that for $k=1$, $\binom{2^k}{2^{k-1}}=2$. This means that $S \equiv 2-2(99) \pmod{8}=-196 \pmod{8} \equiv 4 \pmod{8}$.

Therefore, the largest natural number $n$ for which $2^n$ divides $S$ is $\boxed{2}$.

Comment: As for how to prove that $\binom{2^k}{2^{k-1}} \equiv -2 \pmod{8}$ for $k \ge 2$: observe that as polynomials, $(1+x)^{2^{k-2}} \equiv 1 + x^{2^{k-2}} \pmod{2}$.  Therefore, $(1+x)^{2^k} \equiv (1 + x^{2^{k-2}})^4 \pmod{8}$.  But $(1 + x^{2^{k-2}})^4 = 1 + 4 x^{2^{k-2}} + 6 x^{2^{k-1}} + 4 x^{3 \cdot 2^{k-2}} + x^{2^k}$.  Now take the coefficient of $x^{2^{k-1}}$ on both sides.